# How to transform Measure to Colum in PBI

Tags: powerbi, calculated-columns, measure

i need to make a division, One column over one mesaure, my measure is:

```
VAR Selection =
SELECTEDVALUE ( Manipulated[Business_Unit] )
VAR Selection_Month =
SELECTEDVALUE ( Tasa[Month] )
RETURN
IF (
NOT ( ISBLANK ( Selection ) ),
LOOKUPVALUE (Tasa[MX-USA], Tasa[Area_Month], CONCATENATE(Selection,Selection_Month)),
""
)
```

but when i try to divide my main Col, "Money" over my calculated measure, i have NaN, also i can't convert my measure to Column to do a division between Columns,
Do you know how can i do this?
Thanks !!

Comment: It looks like your measure is outputting text. You can't divide by text.

Comment: i tried to convert to VALUE, also when i made any other operation (only with measures) everything works good,

Comment: can i convert this to value or something?